# Missing Gmail email

Tags: gmail

I found the email I needed in Trash and clicked the box next to it and then correctly clicked "move to inbox". Went to inbox and the email is not there. Went back to trash....not there. Put the name of email in the headline of the inbox...not there. Email has totally disappeared.  I need this because it has the tracking number of a purchase I made and has not arrived when it said it should!!   Any idea where it went?

Comment: did you check "all mail"?

Comment: Your Gmail account isn't linked to any other emails accounts, is it?  Meaning maybe the email went to a different inbox?

Comment: I checked my backup email. Not there either. Pretty sure gone forever.  Thanks